# Using select in Angular in the modal window

Tags: html, angularjs, select, bootstrap-modal

The problem is that this select does not work in it. In which the correspondent should be selected.

However, outside the modal window, this select works fine.

What is the problem?

Modal Window:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="createDocTemplate.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalInstance.title}}</h4>
</div>
<form name="createDocForm">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':createDocForm.docNumber.$invalid}">
            <label for="docNumber" class="control-label">№ DOC</label>
            <input type="text" required
                   ng-model="modalInstance.form.docNumber" class="form-control" id="docNumber" name="docNumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':createDocForm.docDate.$invalid}">
            <label for="docDate" class="control-label">Date</label>
            <input type="text" required
                   ng-model="modalInstance.form.docDate" class="form-control" id="docDate" name="docDate">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':createDocForm.correspondent.$invalid}">
            <label for="correspondent" class="control-label">Correspondent</label>

            <select ng-model="modalInstance.form.correspondent" class="form-control" id="correspondent" name="correspondent">
                    <option ng-repeat="user in demoApp.users">{{user.secondName}} {{user.firstName}} {{user.middleName}}</option>
                    <option>lol</option>

            </select>

        <div ng-show="modalInstance.formError" class="form-group">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Error</span>
                Fill in required fields

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not work? What's the issue you the facing?

Comment: Displays an empty select.
No, data {{user.secondName}} {{user.firstName}} {{user.middleName}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if demoApp.users exists inside modal.

Comment: Ohhh, realy)
Thank you very much)))

Comment: @АлександрПерепечаев I would be grateful if you mark my answer as correct :)

in russian: 
я буду благодарен если Вы отметите мой ответ как правильный)